# Get Query string as it is passed

Tags: url, go

I'm new to `Go`. My question is how to get URL encoded string on stdout.

Below is the URL string I am using to hit an api.

`schooltubeapi/v1/channeldetails?channelName=long%20division%20`.

Below is the code that I am using to get RawQuery

```
url1 := ChannelName
u, _ := url.Parse(url1)
log.Println(u)
u.RawQuery = u.Query().Encode()
log.Println(u)
```

**[Output]**

`long division`

**[Expected]**

`long%20division%20`

I have searched alot But cannot found a similar problem with a solution.

Comment: RawQuery from https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL. Remember: Always read the Go documentation first and read _all_ _of_ _it_.

Answer (score 0):

For url encoded string use `URL` struct of `url` package to get RawQuery as passed in the URI:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    stringValue := "long division "
    t := &url.URL{Path: stringValue}
    encodedString := t.String()
    fmt.Println(encodedString)
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/dyeAtAdc8p-)

In Golang spec for URL. It is stated:-

> that the Path field is stored in decoded form: /%47%6f%2f becomes
>   /Go/. A consequence is that it is impossible to tell which slashes in
>   the Path were slashes in the raw URL and which were %2f. This
>   distinction is rarely important, but when it is, code must not use
>   Path directly. The Parse function sets both Path and RawPath in the
>   URL it returns, and URL's String method uses RawPath if it is a valid
>   encoding of Path, by calling the EscapedPath method.

```
type URL struct {
        Scheme     string
        Opaque     string    // encoded opaque data
        User       *Userinfo // username and password information
        Host       string    // host or host:port
        Path       string    // path (relative paths may omit leading slash)
        RawPath    string    // encoded path hint (see EscapedPath method)
        ForceQuery bool      // append a query ('?') even if RawQuery is empty
        RawQuery   string    // encoded query values, without '?'
        Fragment   string    // fragment for references, without '#'
}
```

For more information Check [Golang spec](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) for `URL`